# Handling query parameters with multiple question marks in Angular 2

Tags: angular, query-string

So basically I couldn't get the correct result with my query parameters. For example we have a query parameter that looks like this:

```
?encryptedId=zxcvbnm?:112233
```

The returned result would just be *zxcvbnm*, the second question mark and all the succeeding characters to it are all omitted.

I've already tried this:

```
this.businessId = this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url).queryParams["bid"];
```

and this:

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((queryParams: Params) => {
      this.businessId = queryParams['id'];
    });
```

but both codes return the same result. I want to capture everything. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode it before passing into the URL with [encodeURIComponent](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp)

Can try `encodeURIComponent('zxcvbnm?:112233')` on your browser console and you will see the result.

So the `?encryptedId=zxcvbnm?:112233` will become `?encryptedId=zxcvbnm%3F%3A112233`

Then from your component, you can retrieve it as the following. I have tested it.

```
export class QueryParamsComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        let queryParams = this.route.snapshot.queryParams;
        const encryptedId = queryParams['encryptedId'];
    }
}
```